# .NET Remoting, why isn't a list remotable?

Tags: c#, .net, remoting, binaryformatter

I'm using `RemotingServices.Marshal` and `Activator.GetObject` to establish a remoting channel between two simple programs residing on the same computer.

```
public class IpcInterface : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public int number = -1;
    public string text = "default";
    public List<String> strings;
}
// A simplification
```

I've confirmed that the channel exists and communication is possible, because both programs are successfully changing `number` and `text` to completely unique values (confirmed).

So I immediately tried doing the same for `strings`.

On one program, I called `strings.Add("1")`. I tried reading the contents of `strings` on the second program. It was *empty*. What's more, the count was `0`. I have no idea why `strings` continues to have `0` objects, as if I never added them. The same thing happens for a `Stack<T>` and `Dictionary<T, K>`, I just can't add any elements to it. Just to be sure there wasn't something weird going on with reference types in general, I also tried putting a `StringBuilder` in the IPC interface class, and that 'state' was successfully maintained across both programs changing its value.

**Question: Why isn't the list of strings being added to, and what's the solution?**

I'm hoping someone with experience can spot this problem right away. I tried Googling for similar questions, but I didn't get any useful results. Surprisingly, I only got 1 good link for googling "*debugging .net remoting transparent proxy*". That's a second question I have, too. How can I debug the transparent proxy object?

1. All objects are instantiated properly (there is no NullReferenceException; in fact, there are no exceptions).

Comment: I had exactly the same questions and issues. Some complex objects passed their members as expected. But a simple list that doesn't work has cost me days of troubleshooting and frustration, especially when a `MarshalByRefObject` is supposed to create a transparent proxy. except it's so transparent it actually does nothing. Confusingly, there are more complicated collections (e.g. `X509Certificate2Collection`) that work fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that `List<T>` is not in itself a `MarshalByRefObject`, rather, it is a serializable class. When you call the `Add()` method on your list, what you're actually doing is asking the remote object to serialise its list, deserialise it locally and then call the method on the local object. Your changes will never be propagated back to the remote instance of the list object.

You will have to provide methods in your `IpcInterface` class to manipulate the list; because this type inherits from `MarshalByRefObject`, the methods will be called on the remote object instead of a locally-deserialised instance.

i.e.

```
public class IpcInterface : MarshalByRefObject {
    public List<String> strings;

    public void Add(string value) {
        strings.Add(value);
    }
}
```

You may also want to expose `strings` as a read-only collection, otherwise you're giving the impression that it can be manipulated directly (which it cannot).

Comment: It didn't worked for me, I'm getting: `System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'Soap Serializer does not support serializing Generic Types : System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String].'
`

Comment: @Codey If you're getting that error then it means your remoting channel is using `SoapFormatter` instead of `BinaryFormatter`. If you can change serialization methods, try using `BinaryFormatter` - otherwise, since generic types are not supported with `SoapFormatter`, try using a non-generic collection type like `StringCollection` instead of `List<string>`.