# HttpChannel MarshalByRefObject that contains list

Tags: c#

I want to implememt [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.remoting.channels.http.httpclientchannel?view=netframework-4.8), I copy pasted the and created a dll (client and server has refernce to this dll) that contains the `RemoteObject`

The remote object looks like:

```
    public class RemoteObject : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        readonly List<String> strings=new List<String>();

        public void Add(string value)
        {
            strings.Add(value);
        }

        public List<String> Get()
        {
            return strings;
        }
    }
```

But when I try to add element from client side like: `new RemoteObject().Add("aaa");` I'm getting the following exception:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'Soap Serializer does not support serializing Generic Types : System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String].'

With the example in the link it works fine:

```
public class RemoteObject : MarshalByRefObject
{
    private int callCount = 0;

    public int GetCount()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GetCount was called.");
        callCount++;
        return(callCount);
    }

}
```

My question is how do I make RemoteObject that can contain some kind of list.

[Related, but doesn't works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13486621/11253551)

Comment: This is an old .NET 1.1 dog, SOAP doesn't support generic types.  Use the HttpServer/ClientProvider constructor that lets you specify [another provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.remoting.channels.binaryclientformattersinkprovider).  Look at WCF.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you,I tried with non generic list an it works fine now